# Can't play Dead By Daylight without PS Plus?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

I have just bought Dead By Daylight and I can't seem to play with just myself as it wants me to pay for ps plus.

Answer (score 9):

Dead by Daylight is a 4 vs 1 *multiplayer* game. As such, you will need a Playstation Network account with an active PS Plus subscription to play the game. There is no singleplayer, offline gameplay.